# Mockito Exception: Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

Tags: java, maven, mockito, extentreports, springmockito

### What I am trying to Do

I am trying to test my class using cucumber and also make extent report on it. I am getting 2 errors in it 1 related to Mockito which is high priority and 2nd related to extent reporting.

### My Code

```
public class ClassA{
    private DataService dataService;

    public int methodA(String dataA, String dataB, String dataC){
        int x;
        //do Something
        return x;
    }
}

public class ClassATest{
    @InjectMock
    private ClassA classA;

    @Mock
    private DataService dataService;

    @BeforeClass
    @io.cucumber.java.Before
    public void setUp() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, Exception {

        System.out.println("---- Before ----");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    
        int value = 10;
        Mockito.when(dataService.methodA(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(value);
    
    
    }
}
```

### My pom.xml

```
    <!-- cucumber dependencies -->
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mockito -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

        
        <!-- CUCUMBER PLUGINS -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>test-ng</projectName>
                        <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation 
                            of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</classificationDirectory>
                        <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Things I have tried

1. Changing the way to mock using Mockito.mock() instead of annotation.
2. Changing Mockito dependency version.
3. Adding Byte-Buddy dependency.
4. Changing Byte-Buddy dependency version.

### My Error regarding Mockito##

---

> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes. If you're not
> sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
>
> Java               : 1.8 JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation JVM
> vendor version : 25.231-b11 JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM)
> 64-Bit Server VM JVM version        : 1.8.0_231-b11 JVM info
> : mixed mode OS name            : Windows 10 OS version         : 10.0
>
> Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
> create type   at
> com.persivia.ptf.notes.consumer.test.NotesProcessThreadTest.setUp(NotesProcessThreadTest.java:56)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)  at
> cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)     at
> cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)  at
> cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:65)
> at
> cucumber.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:16)
> at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)   at
> cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)    at
> cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:42)    at
> cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)  at
> io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:79)
> at
> io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:24)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
> by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type     at
> net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)  at
> net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)     at
> net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
> at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
> at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)   at
> org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)   at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:44)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:19)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:49)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
> at
> org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
> ... 44 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder.appendMostSpecific(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder;
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:83)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
> at
> org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)     ... 62
> more

---

### My Error regarding Extent Reporting

---

> INFO: Unexpected error net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException:
> None report file was added!   at
> net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:62)
> at
> net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
> at
> net.masterthought.cucumber.CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.execute(CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.java:209)
> at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cucumber, so i'm not sure if this solution is transferable to your use case. And my example was written using JUnit 5, thus some different imports.
I'm missing your DataService class and how it relies to ClassA, so i had to make assumptions/simplifications.

```
public class DataService {
    public int methodA(String a, String b, String c) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    private DataService dataService;

    public int methodA(String a, String b, String c) {
        int x;
        x = dataService.methodA(a, b, c);
        return x;
    }
}
```

And finally the test

```
public class ClassATest {
    @InjectMock
    private ClassA classA;

    @Mock
    private DataService dataService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(dataService.methodA(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(1);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, dataService.methodA("", "", ""));
    }
}
```

Thus the main difference to your version is, that the mocking is initialized before each method and not before class.

Comment: No i tried changing it from private and it didn't work also the message "Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes" is for class Access Modifiers.

Comment: Can you try to make **ClassA** static? I remember i had issue's with inner, non-static classes.

Comment: I cant ClassATest is for testing ClassA i cant change it to static as it will effect our system flow.